# WPF Button Change Background during Click

Tags: wpf

This should be simple, therefore it is something I am missing.  I need to change the background color of the a button **during the click only**.  So if a user click the button for 2 days, then the color changes during that two day period.  Once the user is done clicking it returns to the normal color.  Figured this would solve my issue:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
<Setter Property="Button.Effect">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Purple" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Now I know the `IsPressed` does work as the `DropShadowEffect` work correctly during the press.  However the color does not change.  The only reason I could think why is that `IsMouseOver` is taking priority over `IsPressed`.  If this is the case how can I get the two events to "work together?"

Now before people start linking me to this;

[WPF changing button background on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414686/wpf-changing-button-background-on-click) or this [Change Button Background color on EventTrigger in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703266/change-button-background-color-on-eventtrigger-in-wpf) or this [Change Button Background color on EventTrigger in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674662/change-color-of-button-in-wpf-c-sharp-after-click-and-after-2-minutes-retain-the)

Yes those change the color of the button but irrespective on the users click time.  As stated above I only want it effected during the actual user's click, like the `DropShadowEffect`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ahhh, I was right!  The problem was in fact that `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed` where not getting along!  Here is the fix;

```
<Style x:Key="NewButton" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
<Setter Property="Button.Effect">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="5" Opacity="0.5" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsPressed" Value="False" />
            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
    </MultiTrigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Purple" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="0" Opacity="0" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```